# Compute monthly returns for a daily time series containing prices for many assets

Tags: r, quantmod

I have used `quantmod` to download prices for a bunch of assets, and then I've merged the data sets to one time series.

```
library(quantmod)

# Vector of stocks
stocks <- c('AEIS', 'ABC', 'AMGN', 'BBY', 'HRB', 'BKE', 'CPLA', 'GIB')

# Download data sets
getSymbols(stocks)

# Generate time series of prices
prices.data <- do.call(merge, lapply(stocks, function(x) Cl(get(x))))
colnames(prices.data) <- stocks

head(prices.data)

            AEIS    ABC  AMGN   BBY   HRB      BKE  CPLA  GIB
2007-01-03 18.75 23.055 68.40 49.06 23.20 23.00123 25.44 6.73
2007-01-04 18.89 23.145 71.33 49.84 23.28 22.73215 25.19 6.78
2007-01-05 18.63 22.865 71.50 50.00 22.95 21.87720 25.00 6.71
2007-01-08 18.88 23.225 70.93 49.42 23.27 21.76003 25.00 6.76
2007-01-09 18.66 23.150 71.27 49.04 23.48 22.54554 24.84 6.79
2007-01-10 18.93 23.260 71.04 49.41 23.97 22.12458 25.02 6.85
```

I would now like a new time series, `returns.data`, containing the monthly returns for each asset. How do I generate this in the smoothest fashion possible?

Comment: Do you have an example of expected output? I assume you want the same format (1 column per asset), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smoothest possible fashion ... this one liner?

Just use utilities from quantmod `monthlyReturn`:

```
out <- setNames(do.call(cbind, lapply(prices.data, monthlyReturn)), stocks)
```

`setNames` allows you to update the column names without having to write another replacement function (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#special-calls) on another line, which would typically be something like `colnames(out) <- stocks` (I emphasise you don't need to do this).

```
head(out)

                  AEIS          ABC        AMGN         BBY         HRB          BKE       CPLA        GIB
2007-01-31 -0.075733333  0.135979224  0.02880118  0.02731351  0.06034478 -0.049622659 0.11713832 0.15898960
2007-02-28  0.162146509  0.004200000 -0.08682678 -0.07777781 -0.11300813  0.027695074 0.15095000 0.08461538
2007-03-30  0.044687291  0.002851749 -0.13040773  0.04819279 -0.03574698  0.034482762 0.02537457 0.02364066
2007-04-30  0.164448614 -0.052322237  0.14781671 -0.04248766  0.07461977 -0.002240886 0.04203935 0.03810624
2007-05-31  0.001632694  0.024604920 -0.11989395  0.03515539  0.04776647  0.148231314 0.25207430 0.20244716
2007-06-29 -0.076609655 -0.034166340 -0.02054916 -0.03354738 -0.01350781 -0.036674811 0.05187388 0.03792784
```